# Where to process data in MVC

Tags: component, administrator, mvc, custom-component

This may be a very basic question but i am new to this and all the tutorials i watched don't work with processing data before displaying.
I am working on a Administration Component thet is supposed to get data from a database (no problem) and then i want to do a few operations on it before displaying it.

My Question is now: Where in the MVC-Structure do i put my calculation-functions? For my unserstanding it would be logical to outsource it to a helper function - but if that is right, where do i call this helper functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model is the best place to locate business logic. Specific calculation-functions can be assigned to helpers. Then, model frequently calls helper functions.

PD: Well, any object can call helpers as a way to isolate specific routines.